# external config for spdlog or ability to set custom filename for log in ros2

Tags: ros, ros2, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there anything in the pipeline in terms of building ability to read external config files for the default logger, spdlog?

Alternatively, does a method exist or is currently being developed, for setting custom names for log files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364934/external-config-for-spdlog-or-ability-to-set-custom-filename-for-log-in-ros2/) by [MHx](https://answers.ros.org/users/61446/mhx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2020-11-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaik, the implementation of the default logger (spdlog) does not currently support custom log configuration:
https://github.com/ros2/rcl_logging/blob/galactic/rcl_logging_spdlog/src/rcl_logging_spdlog.cpp#L73

If you compile ROS2 from source, you can use log4cxx instead, which does support external configuration. There are however a number of other issues with that (which is why the default logging system was changed to spdlog).

---

Originally posted by [rasmusan-](https://answers.ros.org/users/53040/rasmusan-/) with karma: 51 on 2021-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1